# Is there a shortcut suggestions limit on iOS Shortcuts App?

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts

I've created an intent for Apple Shortcuts app and everything works fine, but not all my shortcut suggestions are visible.
I've noticed that a maximum of 30 items are shown. Is there a limit?

Here how I set the suggestions:

```
var suggestions = [INShortcut]()
    
for exampleItem in exampleItems {
    suggestions.append(INShortcut(intent: exampleItem.getIntent())!)
}
INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
```